# Interactivity not working for SVG HTML file

Tags: html, css, svg, interactive

I am having issues with the interactivity of some areas of my project. The CSS for some of these elements is identical to others with the same animations albeit for the file names. These are the current problems I'm having:

- For the first section, I'm trying to animate so that hovering over "True!" will reveal "Wrong!" on top and will hide the other words, and vice versa.
- Flour bag won't animate
- Milan text won't animate
- Text for penne is static

Folder located here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fAfqgBMDymEZeCi-_OdALoudgNYBeZrs?usp=sharing

Any and all help appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] right here, not at some external link.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Press the [<>] button in the SO editor and **include** your code. Your link to a Google Drive can be gone when you delete that file in the future